# Send task mail notification programmicaly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, task-list

I have a case, where I need to change task `Assigned To` field value. And when it is changed, then it should send notification to new person.

Here is the question, is it possible to send (resend) Task notification email (what seems to be workflow email) with C#?

Otherwise I could use regular `SendEmail` to send my own custom mail body.

It is SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find solution, then this is what I did:

I took source code from default task notification email. Removed some code and modified links for my own needs. Works like a charm :)